# Collecting comments from Reddit, outputting to CSV file

Tags: python, csv, reddit, praw

I'm trying to scrape comments from a certain submission on Reddit and output them to a CSV file.

```
import praw
import csv

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='ClientID', client_secret='ClientSecret', user_agent='UserAgent')

Submission = reddit.submission(id="SubmissionID")

with open('Reddit.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    for comment in submission.comments:
        csvfile.write(comment.body)
```

The problem is that for each cell the comments seem to be randomly split up. I want each comment in its own cell. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe would be helpful if you add what is the raw `submission.comments` data is looking like and what do you expect as a final result in your csv

Answer (score 0):

You are importing the csv library but you are not actually utilizing it. Utilize it and your problem may go away.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

```
import csv
# ...    
comment = "this string was created from your code"
# ...
with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['comment']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'comment': comment})
```

Answer (score 0):

To write a CSV file in Python, use [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), specifically [`csv.writer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer). You import this module at the top of your code, but you never use it.

Using this in your code, this looks like:

```py
with open('Reddit.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    comment_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for comment in submission.comments:
        comment_writer.writerow([comment.body])
```

Here, we use `csv.writer()` to create a CSV writer from the file that we've opened, and we call it `comment_writer`. Then, for each comment, we write another row to the CSV file. The row is represented as a list. Since we only have one piece of information to write on each row, the list contains just one item. The row is `[comment.body]`.

The `csv` module takes care of making sure that values with new lines, commas, or other special characters are properly formatted as CSV values.

---

Note that, for some submissions with many comments, your PRAW code might raise an exception along the lines of `'MoreComments' object has no attribute 'body'`. The [PRAW docs discuss this](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/comments.html), and I encourage you to read that to learn more, but know that we can avoid this happening in code by further modifying our loop:

```py
from praw.models import Comment

# ...

with open('Reddit.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    comment_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for comment in submission.comments:
        if isinstance(comment, Comment):
            comment_writer.writerow([comment.body])
```

---

Also, your code only gets the top level comments of a submission. If you're interested in more, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60116284), which is about how to get more than just top-level comments from a submission.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comprehensive and pedagogical answer!! I really appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing that the cells are not being split randomly, but being split at a comma, space semi-colon. You can choose what character you want the cells to be split at by using the delimiter parameter.

```
import csv

with open('Reddit.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    comments = ['comment one','comment two','comment three']
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='-')
    csv_writer.writerow(comments)
```

Comment: Your code creates `csv_writer` and then doesn't use it. That seems incorrect. Can you correct your answer so that it actually uses the `csv_writer`, so that the question-asker can see how to use it?