# How to extract selftext from Reddit, comments+submissions?

Tags: csv, reddit, text-extraction, praw

to put it simple, I need to get in the easiest way possible a dumping file containing all the comments and posts from a certain subreddit in a specific time range.

Specifically, I want the body of the threads and the body of the comments without any metadata.

I also need to put the output in a .csv file to be run in a software for a linguistic research project (specifically AntConc) for my master thesis. I will probably use [Collecting comments from Reddit, outputting to CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60303124/collecting-comments-from-reddit-outputting-to-csv-file) for the csv output if I manage to work on praw.

I tried looking into both PRAW and pushshift.io with little luck; what I need to do should be pretty straightforward, both these tools are too powerful and feature rich for what i need to do.

```
api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/all/subreddit=askreddit&field=selftext&after=30d&size=50
```

which resulted in nothing. I also tried to replace "all" with "submissions" and "comment", but no results.

with praw :

```
reddit = praw.reddit(my info)
reddit.subreddit('askreddit').submissions(starttimestamp, endtimestamp)
submission.posts.replace_more(limit=None)
for submission in submission.posts.list():
print(comment.body + '\n')
```

In praw I got stuck at the timestamp so I have no idea if the rest below is ok